# SSLError while trying to create EC2 server with knife

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, openssl, chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to create and provision a new EC2 instance with knife, but keep running into an SSL error:

```
$bundle exec knife ec2 server create
ERROR: Excon::Errors::SocketError: hostname "ec2.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I'm running this from a mac (10.7) using ruby 2.0.0p0:

```
$ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

I'm fairly certain I compiled ruby with openssl support correctly. Running `require 'openssl'` from irb returns true. I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1e installed via homebrew.

I also tried running knife with ruby 1.9.3-p194. That has the same result, with a slightly less helpful error message: "ERROR: Excon::Errors::SocketError: hostname does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)". That difference is the result of this pull request, which improved the error message: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/122.

The following output from curl might be relevant:

```
$curl -v https://ec2.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com
* About to connect() to ec2.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 67.215.65.132... connected
* Connected to ec2.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com (67.215.65.132) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: serialNumber=UoFmxu6ta5ecJiIs4su2w-q-u8rxJ/d3; OU=GT55236522; OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12; OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R); CN=*.opendns.com
*    start date: 2012-08-23 10:11:50 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-09-25 12:42:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName does not match ec2.us-east-1b.amazonaws.com
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

Is there something else I need to configure in order to successfully create an EC2 instance with knife?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my knife.rb configuration file, I had this line:

```
knife[:region] = 'us-east-1b'
```

That worked at some point in the past, but the correct current setting is:

```
knife[:region] = 'us-east-1'
```

Removing the 'b' resolves the SSL hostname error:

```
$curl -v https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
* About to connect() to ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 205.251.242.7... connected
* Connected to ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (205.251.242.7) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using RC4-MD5
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Seattle; O=Amazon.com Inc.; CN=ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
*    start date: 2010-10-08 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2013-10-07 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 16 Mar 2013 21:15:51 GMT
< Server: AmazonEC2
<
* Connection #0 to host ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Answer (score 1):

When you install the chef-client on your mac book it will automatically installs the knife and dependent libraries, you dont have to do it manually. You dont have to run with bundle exec, just type knife ec2 server create, you will get the following output

```
** EC2 COMMANDS **
knife ec2 server list (options)
knife ec2 server delete SERVER [SERVER] (options)
knife ec2 server create (options)
knife ec2 instance data (options)
knife ec2 flavor list (options)
```

If you are getting this output then your knife is working properly. And also make sure your knife.rb is configured properly, if you have any problem let me know.

Comment: Installing knife globally (without bundler) didn't change anything. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling chef globally without any luck. I get the same SSL error when I run "knife ec2 server create" without "bundle exec".

Comment: Bundler was a red herring, but I took another look at the knife.rb file because of your answer. Have an upvote.